# Populate R dataframe with a for lopp

Tags: r, dataframe

The output I have now looks like

```
   [2] "DOYLESTOWN HOSPITAL | PA | 10.4"                                              
   [3] "GLENDALE ADVENTIST MEDICAL CENTER | CA | 10.5"                                
   [4] "AVERA HEART HOSPITAL OF SOUTH DAKOTA LLC | SD | 10.5"                         
   [5] "WATERBURY HOSPITAL | CT | 10.6"                                               
   [6] "MAIN LINE HOSPITAL LANKENAU | PA | 10.7"
```

I am using this code to generate that list

```
for (x in df){
  paste(df$name,df$state, df$outcome, sep = " | ")
}
```

Now I'd like to create a dataframe instead and populate it with this data

Expected output

```
                      hospital state rank
   D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL AL   10
ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER AR   14
```

> class(df)  [1]
>
> "data.frame"

Answer (score 1):

We can use:

```
mytext <- c("DOYLESTOWN HOSPITAL | PA | 10.4","GLENDALE ADVENTIST MEDICAL CENTER | CA | 10.5")
splitted <- strsplit(mytext, split="\\|")
hospital <- sapply(splitted, function(x) x[[1]])
state <- sapply(splitted, function(x) x[[2]])
rank <- sapply(splitted, function(x) x[[3]])
result <- data.frame(hospital, state, rank)
> result
                            hospital state  rank
1               DOYLESTOWN HOSPITAL    PA   10.4
2 GLENDALE ADVENTIST MEDICAL CENTER    CA   10.5
```

However, I don't really see the point if you already have the data available in `df`.
Of course if you were just after the syntax, it makes sense.

Please do make your data reproducible next time.

Comment: I already have those variables saved, how do I append them within forloop so I can get a data frame as output? I don't see how you created the df you just wrote result, where's the forloop??

Comment: implicit loops are done using `sapply`.  check out `?apply`, it is useful (and sometimes cited as best practice in R)

Comment: `result <- data.frame(hospital, state, rank)` might be needed for `result`.

Comment: correct. edited

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we may use `read.csv/read.table` if we specify the delimiter correctly

```
read.csv(text = gsub("\\s+\\|\\s+", ",", str1), 
  header = FALSE, col.names = c("hospital", "state", "rank"))
                           hospital state rank
1               DOYLESTOWN HOSPITAL    PA 10.4
2 GLENDALE ADVENTIST MEDICAL CENTER    CA 10.5
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("DOYLESTOWN HOSPITAL | PA | 10.4", 
"GLENDALE ADVENTIST MEDICAL CENTER | CA | 10.5"
)
```